# Shifted reputation display on new profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-graph

On my [reputation points tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437016/bigood?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2015-10-14%2023:52:47Z) on Stack Overflow, in the graph display, things are obviously shifted:

[image]

[image]

I don't know whether the graph is wrong, or the events are not attached to the right day. It happens to me in other Stack Exchange sites too, but it's more obvious on Stack Overflow.

*Note: I'm in GMT+2, if that can help.*